# Getting around JavaScript's lack of goto WITHOUT additional flags

Tags: javascript, goto

How could I emulate the `goto` programming construct in this case?

```
$.fn.hierarchy = function(info, ret) {
    if (info.constructor !== Object) {
        info = {children: info};
        goto label1; // Illegal JavaScript
    }

    if (!info.children) {
        info.children = [];
        goto label2; // Illegal JavaScript
    }

    label1:
    if (info.children.constructor !== Array)
        info.children = [info.children];

    label2:
    /*
    // Forget this code. It's irrelevant to my specific problem
    // (which is that JS doens't allow non-nested conditionals)
    //  and caused much confusion.
    if (!info.tagc)
        info.tagc = info.tag || 'div';
    */
```

I know I could implement exactly *ONE* of these `goto`s as an else clause:

```
$.fn.hierarchy = function(info, ret) {
    if (info.constructor !== Object) {
        info = {children: info};
        //goto label1;
    }

    else if (!info.children) {
        info.children = [];
        goto label2; // Illegal JavaScript
    }

    //label1:
    if (info.children.constructor !== Array)
        info.children = [info.children];

    label2:
    /*
    // Forget this code. It's irrelevant to my specific problem
    // (which is that JS doens't allow non-nested conditionals)
    //  and caused much confusion.
    if (!info.tagc)
        info.tagc = info.tag || 'div';
    */
```

Or:

```
$.fn.hierarchy = function(info, ret) {
    if (info.constructor !== Object) {
        info = {children: info};
        goto label1; // Illegal JavaScript
    }

    if (!info.children) {
        info.children = [];
        //goto label2;
    }

    else {
        label1:
        if (info.children.constructor !== Array)
            info.children = [info.children];
    }

    //label2:
    /*
    // Forget this code. It's irrelevant to my specific problem
    // (which is that JS doens't allow non-nested conditionals)
    //  and caused much confusion.
    if (!info.tagc)
        info.tagc = info.tag || 'div';
    */
```

But I want to have *both* `goto`s. And, no, I don't want additional flags.

---

**EDIT:**

@Luis Espinal: Your proposed solution doesn't work. If `info` is `{children: 'a'}`, your program fails to convert `info.children` to `[a]`.

```
$.fn.hierarchy = function(info, ret) {
    if (info.constructor !== Object) {
        info = {children: info};
        // goto label1; // Illegal JavaScript
        // label1:
        if (info.children.constructor !== Array){
            info.children = [info.children];
        }
    }
    else if (!info.children) {
        info.children = [];
        // goto label2; // Illegal JavaScript
        // label2:
        /*
        // Wrong. This has to be placed outside all of this.
        if (!info.tagc)
        {
            info.tagc = info.tag || 'div';
        }
        */
    }
    /* the following code is missing:

    else {
        // Handles the case when info.constructor === Object
        // from the beginning
        // AND
        // info.children isn't an array
        if (info.children.constructor !== Array)
            info.children = [info.children];
    }
    */
```

---

**EDIT:** Some of you seemed to think the fourth conditional is relevant to my problem. The problem is actually that I cannot do the following:

```
If condition1 Then action1
If !condition1 && condition2 Then action2
If !condition2 && condition3 && regardlessOf(condition1) Then action3
```

Without using flags (temporary boolean variables).

Basically if `condition1` is true, I don't have to test for `condition2`, and, if `condition2` is true, I don't have to test for `condition3`. But, if `condition1 && !condition2`, I might have to test for `condition3`.

Comment: Why do you want to resurrect GOTO. Even in Assembly they tried to get rid of them by introducing IF, ELSE, ENDIF (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language). Structure == Less spaghetti code

Comment: There are legitimate uses for goto. Sometimes, avoiding goto doesn't make your program more clear. Sometimes, avoiding goto forces you to define additional flags which would be needless in a program with gotos. Sometimes, goto + comments explaining why goto is necessary > additional, needless flags.

Comment: There are definitely some legitimate uses for goto, but at least most of them are covered in JavaScript by functions as first-class objects, return, continue, break, break label, and try/finally.  I've posted an answer below that uses break label to get what I think you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function has a non planar control flow graph, and as such cannot be implemented using structured programming logic.
If you are concerned with speed, your best bet would be to duplicate `label 1` and structure the code as follows:

```
$.fn.hierarchy = function(info, ret) {
    if (info.constructor !== Object) {
        info = {children: info};
        //goto label1; // Illegal JavaScript
        //label1:
        if (info.children.constructor !== Array)
        {info.children = [info.children];}
    }
    else{
        if (!info.children) {
            info.children = [];
            //goto label2; // Illegal JavaScript
        }
        else{
            //label1:
            if (info.children.constructor !== Array)
            {info.children = [info.children];}
        }
    }

    //label2:
    if (!info.tagc)
    {info.tagc = info.tag || 'div';}
};
```

Comment: Which is what I don't want to do.

Comment: Why not? I'm genuinely curious

Comment: Because I'm a sloppy idiot and, when I have duplicate instances of the same code, I tend to modify one of the copies without updating the other one. And also, because it's inelegant. Code is meant to be *both* efficiently read by humans (avoid duplication of code) and efficiently executed by computers (avoid executing instructions that don't have to be executed). I don't like compromises.

Comment: Yet you don't want to wrap the code in a function, or use a temporary boolean variable? I get the feeling you're not looking for an answer, you just want to complain that javascript has no goto statement.

Comment: Kind of. I guess two lines of duplicated code won't hurt too much, so I'll take your suggestion, but right now, I'd kill Dijkstra if he weren't already dead.

Comment: @Eduardo - in that case, it's a problem with your code management skills, and not with structured program theory. Dijkstra went a bit overboard with *GOTO=evil*, but his position yielded a massive improvement in the way we used to code, moving away from spaghetti and into efforts to organize code in structures with algebraic properties. 4-5 decades of industrial experience has confirmed the entire software industry that Dijkstra's position was fundamentally right and practically sound.

Comment: @Eduardo - and by following what we know of software, we construct code that is elegant and readable (not by being sloppy.) The task of efficient compilation and execution/interpretation, that you leave it to the compiler/interpreter. There is an entire body of science on that (what, like 5 decades). Last time people had to manually arrange code for efficient execution was when people hand-wired vacuum tubes (or when implementing obscure and efficient embedded code.) None of that applies to the type of jobs JavaScript is for.

Comment: @Luis: It's my task to specify the algorithm I want to use, whether its control flow graph is planar or not. It's the compiler's/interpreter's job to take care of the machine-dependent little details.

Comment: @Eduardo - exactly, and that runs counter to your previous argument of code being meant for both, efficient reading and efficient execution **as if both** were your immediate concern and as if *you have to make a compromise*. *"I don't like compromises"* you said, but that's not a compromise **you** have to make as you are solely in charge of one aspect and not the other.

Comment: @Eduardo - and yes, it is your job to specify your algorithm and whether you control structure is planar or not (**according to tried and true best practices**). By pursuing a design that runs counter to everything we know about software development, counter to existing industrial evidence that recursive function call overhead in JavaScript is usually negligible (specially since JS code is typically I/O - not CPU - bound), arguing for a feature that will never be in JS, you are not doing your job. That is the nutshell of it.

Comment: Structure programming automatically **implies non-planar control flow graphs are bad, period**. It discards an infinite set of possibilities as bad, without actually explaining why. Of course, structured programs are easier to understand, and, ignoring other criteria, a structured program is to be preferred to a non-structured program. But, what if an efficient algorithm **CANNOT BE EXPRESSED** as a structured program? Sorry, to me, algorithms are first, and if a programming paradigm will prevent me from implementing the algorithm I want to implement, I will ditch the programming paradigm.

Comment: And what possible algorithm could you be required to implement in JavaScript that is best implemented without Structured Programming? Are you manipulating stack pointers? Jumping frames? Trampolines? Show me one example of an efficient algorithm *THAT CANNOT BE EXPRESSED* without a goto. Until you do that, you are just hand-waving smoke and mirrors.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe change labels to functions, and gotos to setTimeout(functionname, 0)

For example, instead of:

```
label1:
    // do something
    goto label2

label2:
    // do something
    goto label1
```

try something like this:

```
function label1 () {
    // do something
    setTimeout(label2, 0);
    return; // may be needed if not at the end of function
}

function label2 () {
    // do something
    setTimeout(label1, 0);
    return; // may be needed if not at the end of function
}
```

(You have to use timeouts because first JavaScript doesn't optimize tail calls (yet) and second because you don't want to block the browser and timeout of 0 puts your callback at the end of the event loop)

Comment: [This is of course a valid solution, thus the upvote, but...] <sarcasm>Great. Now library functions are supposed to make up for the lack of programming constructs.</sarcasm> Sorry, I couldn't resist. Why would I want the overhead of *additional functions* if I don't even want the overhead of an additional flag?

Comment: @Eduardo: Well, because [goto statements are considered harmful](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.92.4846&rep=rep1&type=pdf). ;)

Comment: You trade-off maintainability for some space or function call overhead. The language designers thought that was reasonable. So do I.

Comment: I know goto shouldn't be abused. For the record, my policy is "don't use goto if there is a goto-less way to do it that doesn't require additional overhead". But, in this case, avoiding goto costs me an additional flag. And it doesn't even make my code more clear. Goto + comments explaining why the goto > Needless flags or conditional evaluations.

Comment: @Eduardo - Your paranoia about *overhead* is probably just that.

Comment: @Eduardo - can you quantify the overhead of adding those additional functions? If the overhead is such that justifies looking for goto structures, then either you are using the wrong language (or computing model), or there is something significantly wrong in the design. Even in real-time embedded development, gotos are typically not used unless you can quantify a reason for them or you have a very obscure (and legitimately needed) algorithm or structure. We are talking JavaScript here.

Comment: @Eduardo - besides, the only thing you are shaving off with a goto over a function call is pushing the return address and references passed by value (if any). This is hardly an overhead considering that the main overhead in JavaScript is strictly IO and html rendering.

Comment: `$.fn.hierarchy` happens to be a **HIGHLY** recursive function.

Comment: This is 2011, not 1970. Modern virtual machines (like Rhino or Sun's JVM) with strict pass-by-value references to structures are built to handle that efficiently. This is not like making recursive calls passing **entire structures** in dumb copy pass-by-value fashion (as one would see in C or Pascal.) Again, you have to characterize the cost, even in highly recursive functions. You must have an idea on the average call weight specific to your app(s).

Comment: And even if that wasn't possible (very unlikely), you have not much choice. Goto is not there, period. So all you can do is structure your code as cleanly as possible (as in this particular case either with flag variables or extra functions). There is an entire body of knowledge out there on how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Unless my eyes are failing me or I'm missing an obscure side-effect, the first goto-ridden example is equivalent to the following if-else based version (bless 1960's **structured** programming constructs):

```
$.fn.hierarchy = function(info, ret) {
    if (info.constructor !== Object) {
        info = {children: info};
        // goto label1; // Illegal JavaScript
        // label1:
        if (info.children.constructor !== Array){
            info.children = [info.children];
        }
    }
    else if (!info.children) {
        info.children = [];
        // goto label2; // Illegal JavaScript
        // label2:
        if (!info.tagc)
        {
            info.tagc = info.tag || 'div';
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your eyes are failing you, and there is no obscure side-effect.

Comment: Close, label 2 has to be run by both, so remove it from the else clause. (Oh, and Eduardo, try not to be such a wanker)

Comment: What do you mean by "wanker"? Having conditionals that do not nest?

Comment: No, being a "wanker" by not explaining what I missed in my first pass (as david did.) Indeed, mea culpa, label 2 has to be run by both. In that case, just follow **Böhm & Jacopini's theorem** to its conclusion, and enclose the bloody label2 block into a function being called from both if blocks. The only time I've ever had a need for goto was when implementing inevitably nasty error handling code (think longjmp/setjmp) in C (or when coding in assembler). Only a couple of times in a HL in 17 years of practice. Sorry man, this is JavaScript, not some obscure C/asm code dealing with interrupts.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript does have a break label statement that can be used to exit any block of code early.  I believe you would get the effect you are seeking considering your first code snippet if you did something like this:

```
var ft = function(info, ret) {
    label2: {
        label1: {
            if (info.constructor !== Object) {
                info = {children: info};
                break label1;
            }
            else if (!info.children) {
                info.children = [];
                break label2;
            }
        }
        //label1:
        if (info.children.constructor !== Array)
            info.children = [info.children];
    }
    // label2:
    /*
    // Forget this code. It's irrelevant to my specific problem
    // (which is that JS doens't allow non-nested conditionals)
    //  and caused much confusion.
    if (!info.tagc)
        info.tagc = info.tag || 'div';
    */
};
```

Break label is not really quite goto, and doesn't allow you to write the kind of spaghetti that goto would.  It's somewhat structured in that it only exits its current block early, so you could not avoid the label2 processing after jumping to label1, but then your original code snippet didn't so this might fulfill what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

maybe something like this?

```
  $.fn.hierarchy = function(info, ret) {
    if(((info.constructor !== Object && info = {children: info}) ||
      (!!info.children || (info.children = [] && false))) &&
      /* label1: */
      info.children.constructor !== Array) {
      info.children = [info.children];      
    }

    /* label2: */
    /*
    // Forget this code. It's irrelevant to my specific problem
    // (which is that JS doesn't allow non-nested conditionals)
    //  and caused much confusion.
    if (!info.tagc) {
      info.tagc = info.tag || 'div';
    }
```